# Using Intervalmatch without a synthetic key

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I'm attempting to use `IntervalMatch` function to join two tables together a below

```
InvoiceData:
  load Supplier 
  , SupplierName    
  , SupplierValue   
  , Invoice 
  , InvoiceDate 
  , DueDate 
  , OrigInvValue    
  , OrigDiscValue   
  , PaymentReference    
  , PaymentNumber   
  , PostValue   
  , Value   
  , MthInvBal1  
  , MthInvBal2  
  , MthInvBal3  
  , Currency    
  , ConvRate
  , DatabaseName&'.'&Supplier&'.'&Invoice as SupplierInvoice
  , DatabaseName as Company
  ;

  SQL Select ****;

CurrencyRates:
Load date(floor([StartDateTime])) as [StartDate]
    ,date(floor([EndDateTime])) as [EndDate]
    ,[Currency] as BaseCurrency
    ,[CADDivision]
    ,[CHFDivision]
    ,[EURDivision]
    ,[GBPDivision]
    ,[JPYDivision]
    ,[USDDivision]
    ,[CADMultiply]
    ,[CHFMultiply]
    ,[EURMultiply]
    ,[GBPMultiply]
    ,[JPYMultiply]
    ,[USDMultiply];
SQL SELECT [CR].[StartDateTime]
     , [CR].[EndDateTime]
     , [CR].[Currency]
     , [CR].[CADDivision]
     , [CR].[CHFDivision]
     , [CR].[EURDivision]
     , [CR].[GBPDivision]
     , [CR].[JPYDivision]
     , [CR].[USDDivision]
     , [CR].[CADMultiply]
     , [CR].[CHFMultiply]
     , [CR].[EURMultiply]
     , [CR].[GBPMultiply]
     , [CR].[JPYMultiply]
     , [CR].[USDMultiply]
FROM [Lookups].[CurrencyRates] [CR];

IntervalMatch:
IntervalMatch (InvoiceDate)
Load distinct [StartDate],[EndDate] Resident CurrencyRates;
```

From reading the literature, I don't think the should be a synthetic key between the table interval match and the currency rates, however, my data model is still showing this. Is this correct?

[image: data model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a synthetic key everytime any two tables are linked with more than one field (in your case StartDateTime and EndDateTime).

Looking at the article from Henric Cronström on Qlik Design Blog (https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2013/04/04/intervalmatch) you can read that :

> Further, the data model contains a composite key (the FromDate and ToDate fields) which will manifest itself as a QlikView synthetic key. But have no fear. This synthetic key should be there; not only is it correct, but it is also optimal given the data model. You do not need to remove it.

So it seems only natural you'll get that synthetic key.

Comment: Perfect, didn't have this link before but something based off it not explaining the link